# Show that G is Hamiltonian for $n \ge 4$ with $V = {2, 3, ... , n}$

Tags: graph-theory

for all $ n \ge 4$ show that G=(V,E) is an hamiltonian Graph iif n is odd. also show that G is not hamiltonian if n is even. *The graph is non-oriented*

$V = {2,3,...,n}$

$E = {i,j} \in V X V | gcd(i,j) = 1$

So I tryed for n = 5.
I have $S = { (2,3) , (2,5), (3,4), (3,5), (4,5) }$

[image]

Then I tryed for n = 6
I have $S = { (2,3) , (2,5), (3,4), (3,5), (4,5), (5,6) }$

[image]

First off, is this part correct ?

I can see that the second one is not hamiltonian, the 6 is causing it not to be.
Is it because the 5 has a degree of 4, which is even ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a hint, here are two pieces of information which will be useful for you.

First, note that consecutive numbers are always adjacent since $\gcd(k,\ k+1)=1$.

Secondly, an even numbered vertex is adjacent to only odd numbered vertices.

Comment: I can see why the first information is usefull... not sure about the second one.

Comment: @Dave Suppose you have a Hamiltonian cycle. Write down the parity of the elements in the cycle. What can you say about the number of even elements and the number of odd elements?

Comment: So my final answer is  if n is odd, I have a cycle. Because of gcd(k,mk+1)=1 , and gcd(n,2) = 1 too. Then for n even, I have that g doesn't have a cycle. because even numbers are adjacents only to odd, so gcd(n,2) != 1, is this right ? Thanks EuYu

Comment: @Dave The first part is right because you can take $2,3,\cdots,n$ as a Hamiltonian cycle for odd $n$. But the second part is off. The reason you can't have a Hamiltonian cycle for even $n$ is because there are _more_ even vertices than odd vertices in that case. There must be an odd vertex separating any two even vertices in the Hamiltonian cycle so it follows that a necessary requirement for the existence that the number of odd vertices be greater than or equal to the number of even vertices.